# How do I recreate a correlation matrix to run p.adjust?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I'm new to r and I need to use the rmCorr package to calculate repeated measures correlations (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmcorr/rmcorr.pdf). I have 5 participants and 12 variables. rmCorr outputs a list with important values such as r, p, df and CI. rmCorr does not support p-value adjustment so I will need to extract the p values from the list output by rmCorr to calculate the false discovery rate. The syntax for rmCorr is as follows:

```
rmcorr(subjectID, variable1, variable2, mydata)
```

I'm hoping I can automate the correlations by feeding in the 12 variables (column names). I'd then need to extract the r value from each of the objects and reconstruct two matrices (one r value and one p value):

```
var1x2$p  |
var1x3$p  |  var2x3$p  |
var1x4$p  |  var2x4$p  | var3x4$p  |  etc
```

I'd then run the P values into p.adjust and end up with an adjusted matrix:

```
var1x2$p.adjust  |
var1x3$p.adjust  |  var2x3$p.adjust  |
var1x4$p.adjust  |  var2x4$p.adjust  | var3x4$p.adjust  |  etc
```

Is something like this possible? Sorry if the syntax is wrong, I am very new to r.

Sample data

```
structure(list(subjectID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DSTSpeed = c(5.4225, 
6.8532, 5.6649, 5.6137, 6.5338, 6.9774), DSTError = c(0.060606, 
0.11111, 0.032258, 0.0625, 0.068966, 0.11538), CRTSpeed = c(0.46195, 
0.5066, 0.53191, 0.48758, 0.50286, 0.47727), CRTError = c(0.017241, 
0.034483, 0, 0, 0.033898, 0.016949), KSS = c(4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 6L), SIQPhys = c(1.4, 2, 2.8, 3.6, 3.4, 2.2), SIQCog = c(4, 
3.8, 4.2, 4.2, 5.2, 3.8), TotalSleep = c(7.66416666666667, 7.49611111111111, 
7.28944444444444, 7.78611111111111, 7.46916666666667, 12.8872222222222
), SleepEfficiency = c(0.85775, 0.75881, 0.69097, 0.80629, 0.84559, 
0.73939), ProportionSWS = c(0.063709, 0.31109, 0.2135, 0.2107, 
0.46937, 0.2988), EDA = c(0.77086, 1.4112, 1.5735, 2.168, 1.0156, 
1.7074), WakingEDA = c(0.031424, 0.020836, 0.022987, 0.022799, 
0.020879, 0.28959), temp = c(34.904, 35.414, 35.056, 35.248, 
35.39, 35.105), WakingTemp = c(35.999, 35.636, 35.749, 35.336, 
35.66, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f8ba48128e0>)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Provide a sample of your data or the matrix with `dput`

Comment: You might also take a look at stats.stackexchange.com or the r-help mailing list (a web search will find it).

Answer (score -1):

We added a new function to the rmcorr package (>=0.5.0) for calculating correlations among all specified pairs. Here's an example of using p.adjust() with output from the new function:

```
install.packages(rmcorr)
require(rmcorr)

dist_rmc_mat <- rmcorr_mat(participant = Subject, 
                           variables = c("Blindwalk Away",
                                         "Blindwalk Toward",
                                         "Triangulated BW",
                                         "Verbal",
                                         "Visual matching"),
                           dataset = twedt_dist_measures,
                           CI.level = 0.95)
                           
#Third component: Summary
dist_rmc_mat$summary

#p-values only
dist_rmc_mat$summary$p.vals

#Vector of original, unadjusted p-values for all 10 comparisons
p.vals <- dist_rmc_mat$summary$p.vals

p.vals.bonferroni <- p.adjust(p.vals, 
                              method = ("bonferroni"),
                              n = length(p.vals))

p.vals.fdr <- p.adjust(p.vals, 
                       method = ("fdr"),
                       n = length(p.vals))

#All p-values together
all.pvals <- cbind(p.vals, p.vals.bonferroni, p.vals.fdr)
colnames(all.pvals) <- c("Unadjusted", "Bonferroni", "fdr")
round(all.pvals, digits = 5)
```